# Yup dataURI validation

Tags: base64, yup

I have Field for img in my Formik-form (React), which could be **link** or **dataURI**

How to check with Yup that a valid value is entered in the Field?

Now I use:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    img_url: Yup.string().url(),
  });
```

But it gives an error if dataURI is entered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to specify schema as one of two types: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/321

However you can dynamically return a schema with Yup.lazy(): https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/647. If the img_url begins with 'data', return schema for data URI using Yup.string().matches(), otherwise, return schema for url with Yup.string().url()

You can find the gist and discussion about data URI regex [here](https://gist.github.com/bgrins/6194623)

**This should work:**

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    img_url: Yup.lazy((value) =>
        /^data/.test(value)
          ? Yup.string()
              .trim()
              .matches(
                /^data:([a-z]+\/[a-z0-9-+.]+(;[a-z-]+=[a-z0-9-]+)?)?(;base64)?,([a-z0-9!$&',()*+;=\-._~:@/?%\s]*)$/i,
                'Must be a valid data URI',
              )
              .required()
          : Yup.string().trim().url('Must be a valid URL').required(),
      ),
  });
```

Note: I've added trim() so that you can have extra whitespaces around the URL or the data URI for img_url to still be considered valid. Also, I made img_url required so that it is considered invalid if empty. You might or might not want this based on your use case.

**Here's a version without trim() or required():**

```
validationSchema={Yup.object({
      img_url: Yup.lazy((value) =>
        /^data/.test(value)
          ? Yup.string().matches(
              /^data:([a-z]+\/[a-z0-9-+.]+(;[a-z-]+=[a-z0-9-]+)?)?(;base64)?,([a-z0-9!$&',()*+;=\-._~:@/?%\s]*)$/i,
              'Must be a valid data URI',
            )
          : Yup.string().url('Must be a valid URL'),
      )
```